# How to check if user password is set in mysql?

Tags: mysql, authentication

I need to run automated checks against new servers. One of those checks is to detect if user (or `root`) password is set or not. But..

```
mysql> SELECT host, user, password FROM mysql.user;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Server version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Can you share us your data tables please? We can't workout without it

Comment: Column name is Password not password

Comment: Try `authentication_string` as column name instead off password... MySQL 5.7 and up dont have a column named `password` in the mysql.user table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: Hey! Why downvotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL versions 5.7 or higher doesnt have a column named password in mysql.user table. 
MySQL versions 5.7 or higher use the column authentication_string instead.

So you query should be:

```
SELECT host, user, authentication_string FROM mysql.user
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the end. So, if the field is empty, password is not required, right? Or login disabled?

Comment: @anatoly techtonik if authentication_string is NULL password is not required

Comment: (Note: This is only a small extension to the answer of @RaymondNijland)
If you are using MySQL version >= 5.7 and want to know if `root` access is protected by password, than you can use this:

`mysql -Nse "select count(*) from mysql.user where user = 'root' and authentication_string is null"`

Answer (score 2):

In case someone with a similar search query to the one I used finds this, and for the sake of completeness:

One alternative I found when trying to find out whether a user (root in this case) has a password from the command line (as in, bash, zsh, etc., not the ) is this:

```bash
sudo mysql -u root -e 'quit' &> /dev/null
echo "$?"
```

If this returns `0`, the user does not have a password. For `if`-statements:

```bash
if sudo mysql -u root -e 'quit' &> /dev/null; then
    # Code to run if the user has no password
else
    # Code to run if the user does have a password
fi
```